# Sort by condition

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel

I'm busy with a query to get Groups and Items ( separate models but linked )
I want to do the same as was don't for items and that is to order by `$sortColumn` if not null else sort by `description`

I'm unsure how t implement this in the given query to replace the `->orderBy('description', 'asc')` with the condition.

```
return $this->model->with( [ 'items' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy(\DB::raw("CASE WHEN ".$sortColumn." IS NOT NULL THEN ".$sortColumn."::text ELSE description END"));
}])
->where("hos_id",$hos_id)
->orderBy('description', 'asc')
->get();
```

I was thinking maybe

`->orderBy(\DB::raw("CASE WHEN ".$sortColumn." IS NOT NULL THEN ".$sortColumn."::text ELSE description END"));`

instead of

`->orderBy('description', 'asc')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess simply

```
...
->orderBy(DB::raw('CASE WHEN ...'))
...
```